# Conditially using an object property

Tags: javascript

I have the following ternary:

```
exceptionType == 'Asset' ? selection = selectedAssets.find(function(obj) {return obj.fixedTitle === element}) : selection = dedupedAssets.find(function(obj) {return obj.fixedTitle === element});
```

I am conditionally assigning the variable `selection` to the value returned by `find()`. The functions are extremely similar, with the only difference being the array that is targeted.

Is there a way I can shorten this even further?

Comment: Your ternary is kind of backwards I think... should be like `selection = exceptionType == 'Asset' ? selectedAssets.find(function(obj) {return obj.fixedTitle === element}) : dedupedAssets.find(function(obj) {return obj.fixedTitle === element});`

Comment: @tymeJV. A mistake on my part. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator to know what items to be iterated on and use the logic run once instead of duplicating it.

```
const itemsToIterate = exceptionType == 'Asset' ? selectedAssets : dedupedAssets;

const items = itemsToIterate.find(function(obj) {return obj.fixedTitle === element});
```

You can tweak this a bit to make it even shorter.

```
const itemsToIterate = exceptionType == 'Asset' ? selectedAssets : dedupedAssets;

const items = itemsToIterate.find(({ fixedTitle }) => fixedTitle === element);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your boolean condition as an index to get the right array to apply find to:

```
const selection = [dedupedAssets, selectedAssets][+(exceptionType === 'Asset')]
  .find(o => o.fixedTitle === element);
```

Using the operator `+`, `false` will be converted to 0 and `dedupedAssets` will be returned, and `true` will be converted to 1 and `selectedAssets` will be returned.

**Indexing example**

```js
const a = [{ title: 'hello' }];
const b = [{ title: 'world' }];

console.log([a, b][+false].find(o => o.title === 'hello'));
console.log([a, b][+true].find(o => o.title === 'world'));
```